# passing string value as a parameter to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I`m trying to pass a string value to a JavaScript parameter.
this is my html code

```
<input type="submit"  value="Edit" onclick="edit(<?php echo $key; ?> );" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" >
```

this is my JavaScript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function edit(id){
window.location.href="http://localhost/koko/edit-post.php?id="+id;
}
</script>
```

But this didn't work for me. How I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the type of `$key` is `string` you need to surround it in quotes. Use quotes to the parameter.

```
onclick="edit('<?php echo $key; ?>');"
//            ^                   ^
```

**Better way:**

As the `name` what you want in the function, you can get it by using the `element.name`.

See the comments highlighted in the code below:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Edit" onclick="edit(this);" name="<?php echo $key; ?>">
<!--                                            ^^^^ Pass the element instance to the function -->
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function edit(el) {
    //        ^^ // Get the element instance here
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/koko/edit-post.php?id=" + el.name; // Use element.name to get the `$key` value.
    //                                                                 ^^^^^^^
}
</script>
```